# Is there an eclipse formatter which allows tab on line starting but spaces only after?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

As far as I understand people who hate tabs hate it, because it is used sometimes for formatting comments and so on. I would never do such thing. I think if I want to have formatted comments, I should use Javadoc.

I am personally sick from having spaces for indentation (so at the start of the lines). It is harder to edit the lines, slower to indent and so on.

Is there any way to format the code in a way that for indentation TABs are used, but for the rest of the lines all TABs are replaced with spaces?
Then the both the TAB haters and me would be happy.

**So I want to enable TABs in my formatter for line indentation only. Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that "Mixed" tab policy does what I want. See below:
[image]